# Filtering timestamp record by range

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index-tuning

So i am new at optimizing SQL and here is my query:

```
    COUNT (SI_2_STRIPPED.RESOURCE_UUID) AS COMPLETIONS
FROM
    (SELECT SI2.STATISTIC_ID,
            SS.RESOURCE_UUID
        FROM STATISTICS_STATISTIC SS,
            STATISTICS_INTERACTIVEFORMATSTATISTIC SI2
        WHERE SI2.STATISTIC_ID = SS.ID
            AND SS.START_TIME >= '2022-01-01T00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
            AND SS.START_TIME < '2022-01-31T00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
            AND SI2.DONE = TRUE ) SI_2_STRIPPED
JOIN
    (SELECT IFI.UUID
        FROM INTERACTIVE_FORMATS_INTERACTIVEFORMAT IFI,
            CLIENTS_CLIENT CC
        WHERE IFI.DELETED = FALSE
            AND CC.ID = IFI.CLIENT_ID
            AND IFI.COMPLETED = TRUE
            AND IFI.ACTIVE = 'false' ) IFI_STRIPPED ON SI_2_STRIPPED.RESOURCE_UUID = IFI_STRIPPED.UUID
GROUP BY IFI_STRIPPED.UUID;
```

[image: This is the Explain Analyze from Postgres]

SI2 is a table with about 250k rows.

SS is a table with about 32 million rows. The range of SS dates is about 9 million and the first nested select returns 24k.

Idk why it is not making an index scan on the date range, I think it would be faster

I have an index on ss.start_time and almost all ids.

Idk what's going on but it takes a lot of time. This query returns about 40 rows. Any tips? I previously had the Between operator but I changed it because apparently, it was not very efficient

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: The execution plan is better shared as formatted text, not as a screenshot. You can also consider sharing it through https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: Since the date filter only removed one row, it is hard to see how using an index on it would help much.  Turn on track_io_timing then include BUFFERS in the plan, and show it as text not images.